# Recursive Algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, recursion

Hey im trying to create a list of names (with extensions) of all files in the directory, and all files within all, but i need to use a recursive algorithm. Im not sure if im on the right track !!! Quite new to C#

Comment: 1) Why do you *need* a recursive algorithm?  This can be achieved non-recursively.  2) `Recursive` means that your method calls itself in some way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061957/get-all-files-and-directories-in-specific-path-fast

Comment: My software engineering friend said it would be easier using the recursive algorithm

Comment: How about `FileInfo[] files = pi.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`? "Easy" and "recursive" together in one sentence... ^_^

Comment: This seems to be a homework. Check out the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c1sez4sc.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do this sort of thing with a Queue:

```
// Make sure rootDir exists first...

var files = new List<string>();
var dirs = new Queue<string>();
dirs.Enqueue(rootDir);

while(dirs.Count > 0 ) {

  var dir = dirs.Dequeue();

  foreach( var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(dir) ) {
    files.Add(fileName);
  }

  foreach( var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir) ) {
    dirs.Enqueue(subDir);
  }
}

// Now populate your list with the files collection.
```

Comment: +1 for not littering the Stack with useless function calls which cannot be inlined !

Comment: +1 for this pattern. Although I still like recursion more, as I think its easier to follow (shame about the lack of Tail in the C#->CLR compiler). However I prefer to use yield rather than a List.

Comment: Yeah, my actual code that this is based on is implemented as an iterator block - I'm using it to walk a directory structure of about 1,000,000 xml files...

Comment: +1. This is educational. Also simply using [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) will achieve the same with less code, including iterator version [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) (4.0+).

Comment: Actually thinking a little deeper about this example, I think, assuming I ignore Alexei (great shout by the way). That I would divide the problem into two function. "Recursive get all Directories" and "Enumerate each file in a directory". Switch to using Enumerable GetFile/GetDirectory. Reason being is that you can get the first result faster when using concurrency.