# Determining a FileAttribute for a file in case of "Access Denied":

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, file, access-denied

In my network, there are some files whose access is simply blocked.

A user cannot open nor read the file.

When I try to open the file, the only message that I get is "Access Denied".

```
 bool isReadOnly = ((File.GetAttributes(Path) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) ==   FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

I tried other options available under FileAttributes class. Nothing is matched for "Access Denied".

In short, how do I know whether a file is access-denied to me or not in c#. I am using WPF and visual studio .net 2010

Whenever I try to access it through code, I simply get an exception. When I try to open it manually I get something like "Access Denied."

```
try
{
 IEs = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDirectoryToBeSearched, sValidExtensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                      from str in File.ReadLines(file)
                      where (str.IndexOf(sSearchItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                      select file;
}

  catch
 {
      MessageBox ("Exception arised");
 }
```

Even If used try catch, exception is not handled because of LINQ query. Any solutions ?>

Comment: You need to open it with try and catch

Comment: I added a try catch. Even then not working!

Comment: the exception is not been thrown to catch statement. The execution breaks at point "from str in File.ReadLines(file)" and is never thrown down to catch statement!

Comment: It is stopping there since you're debugging. Press F5 again or run without debug. Anyway, if a single file will cause a problem, all processing is stopped. You need to do try and catch for each file separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using LINQ try using recursion, that way if a file or folder access is denied the rest of procedure will continue. Example bellow.

```
private void SearchDirectory(string folder)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {
        try 
        {
            // do work;
        }
        catch 
        {
            // access to the file has been denied
        }
    }
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    {
        try 
        {   
             SearchDirectory(subDir);
        }
        catch 
        {
            // access to the folder has been denied
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is one that I need to do next! But, the search operations are pretty fastest with LINQ. Any ideas how to handle such things with the same query itself? !

Comment: You will need to implement something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559064/is-there-a-way-of-recover-from-an-exception-in-directory-enumeratefiles

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check the `FileAttributes`, you need to check the security lists.

You can look at the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) to see how to work with the `FileSecurity` class.

Comment: If i use FileAttributes, I have only three options Read,Write,read-write. Can u guide me in proceeding after this ?