# What is the fastest way to calculate a Windows folders size?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I need to calculate the size of hundreds of folders, some will be 10MB some maybe 10GB, I need a super fast way of getting the size of each folder using C#.

My end result will hopefully be:

Folder1 10.5GB

Folder2 230MB

Folder3 1.2GB

...

Comment: There's no way to do this in C#. C# has no features for accessing the file system. You're going to have to use the .NET Framework or the Win32 API.

Comment: Hi John, How would I do this using .Net or the Win32 API? Any idea which is quickest or are both slow?

Comment: @john: I think "C# has no features for accessing the file system" could be construed incorrectly, mainly because of System.IO. I understand what you mean, but to the passerby it might imply something otherwise.

Comment: @RandomNoob: I hope the passersby take it as the fact that C# is not the same as the .NET Framework.

Comment: @John Saunders: that is a particularly pendantic point. The OP already tagged the question 'filesystem' and '.net'. If I were a VB.net programmer, I'd likely phrase the question in terms of VB.net in order to solicit answers written in VB.net rather than C#.

Comment: @JBR: I'm aware it's pedantic - If VB.NET were in the title, I'd remove it as well, and make sure it was in the tags. A particular annoyance was that in the title, it said "Using C# what is the fastest way", which I just now realized is not an instance of the problem I was trying to solve. This is not one of those posts that say, "C# Regex" or "VB.NET Threading", and I should have fixed the title without the pedantic comment (which I now wish I could delete).

Comment: it's a shame that the Windows Filesystem doesn't cheat like MacOS does and it internally stores the size of the directory as a Filesystemobject against each directory and then updates that value for you as files/directories are added/removed. Then there is no calculation required, just read the value... but I digress :-(

Comment: @Paul: how dows the MAC handle clusters, or remote folders, whose size may change out from under it?

Comment: @John: it's been quite some time since I wrote apps on MacOS. SAN, Cluster etc, didn't need to be considered, it was either Local or Mount off Server. Without knowing for sure if this feature even still exists, you'd expect the server manages that as filesystems move etc.

Comment: @Paul: nice ring. However, based on my experience with emulating Mac file systems on foreign platforms, I'd guess the answer is that this value is faked, and should not be depended upon. I had that issue when the foreign file system couldn't know some quantity until the file was read - yet you had to lie to the Mac to say that you knew.

Comment: @LeeW, please check my answer given below.  I know it's really late, but I found some time yesterday/today to solve your problem. I have edited it into my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this in .Net; you will have to loop through every file and subdir.
See the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) to see how it's done.

Comment: It seems slow in Windows too so maybe there isn't a fast method, calculating the size for 100s or 1000s of large folders may not be feasible then :-(

Comment: After reading all the comments I've decided against doing this, is was to be a nice to have feature but the overhead is to great. Thanks all.

Answer (score 37):

Add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime and use:

```
Scripting.FileSystemObject fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
Scripting.Folder folder = fso.GetFolder([folder path]);
Int64 dirSize = (Int64)folder.Size;
```

If you just need the size, this is *much* faster than recursing.

Comment: Example of how MUCH faster for a directory with 900K files and a size of 9.5 GB: this method: 250ms, recursive method:~15 seconds.

Comment: D*nm! Did this, it is about 90% faster! Absolutely amazing! If I could vote up more than once I did it as this is an amazing thing. Any comments about if there's a catch with this COM reference?

Comment: I am not aware about "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". I have searched google but didn't find any satisfactory answer. 

Could you please assist me how can I add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Framework 4.5.

Comment: You can also add the reference by going to Add Reference > COM > Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Comment: Size is `dynamic {double}` in the Locals window `var size = new Scripting.FileSystemObject().GetFolder(path).Size;`

Comment: please add System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folder);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fso);

Comment: although the size is dynamic, it internally uses "double"

Comment: I'm having trouble with this when passing a drive letter; e.g. C: or D:. Anyone else?

Comment: and now uses internally object{int} ?

Comment: Does anyone know what API FileSystemObject.Size is using to get/calculate the size?

Comment: @JackUkleja `FileSystemObject` is implemented by `scrrun.dll`, which implements `FolderObject.get_Size` using `Kernel32.dll!FindFirstFileW` and `Kernel32.dll!FindNextFileW` - while (in .NET 6.0,  at least), `FileSystemInfo` does almost everything via the (multipurpose) function `NtQueryDirectoryFile`.

Answer (score 13):

OK, this is terrible, but...

Use a recursive dos batch file called dirsize.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF %1x==x GOTO start
IF %1x==DODIRx GOTO dodir
SET CURDIR=%1
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`%0 DODIR`) DO SET ANSWER=%%A %CURDIR%
ECHO %ANSWER%
GOTO end
:start
FOR /D %%D IN (*.*) DO CALL %0 "%%D"
GOTO end
:dodir
DIR /S/-C %CURDIR% | FIND "File(s)"
GOTO end
:end
```

Note: There should be a tab character after the final "%%A" on line 5, not spaces.

This is the data you're looking for.  It will do thousands of files fairly quickly.  In fact, it does my entire harddrive in less than 2 seconds.

Execute the file like this `dirsize | sort /R /+25` in order to see the largest directory listed first.

Good luck.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me... when run against my harddrive (`cd C:/`, then `dirsize.bat`) it takes around a minute and echoes "ECHO is disabled" 9 times. (about the time it takes, it's not an SSD but a hybrid, and I have 505k files and 233k folders)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, but there's no fast=true setting when it comes to getting folder sizes, you have to add up the file sizes.

```
    private static IDictionary<string, long> folderSizes;

    public static long GetDirectorySize(string dirName)
    {
        // use memoization to keep from doing unnecessary work
        if (folderSizes.ContainsKey(dirName))
        {
            return folderSizes[dirName];
        }

        string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(dirName, "*.*");

        long b = 0;
        foreach (string name in a)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
            b += info.Length;
        }

        // recurse on all the directories in current directory
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dirName))
        {
            b += GetDirectorySize(d);
        }

        folderSizes[dirName] = b;
        return b;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        folderSizes = new Dictionary<string, long>();
        GetDirectorySize(@"c:\StartingFolder");
        foreach (string key in folderSizes.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("dirName = " + key + " dirSize = " + folderSizes[key]);
        }

        // now folderSizes will contain a key for each directory (starting
        // at c:\StartingFolder and including all subdirectories), and
        // the dictionary value will be the folder size
    }
```

Comment: Where is the initial call to GetDirectorySize()? Without this, the code does nothing as folderSizes is empty.

Comment: Also, folderSizes will also contain all subdirectories whereas it seems the OP just wants the sizes of the top level.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson - Yep, in one of my edits I accidentally took out that initial call. Thanks for pointing it out.  The dictionary will contain all the results, but the OP can use the ones he/she needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click a large directory then properties you can see that it takes significant amount of time to calculate the size... I don't think we can beat MS in this. One thing you could do is index the sizes of directories/subdirs, if you are going to calculate them over and over again... that would significantly increase the speed.

You could use something like this to calculate directory size in C# recursively

```
static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    long size = 0;

    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        size += file.Length;
    }

    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = directory.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
    {
        size += DirSize(dir);
    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dot Net Pearls](http://dotnetperls.com/directory-size) has a method similar to the ones described here.  It's surprising that the [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class doesn't have a method to do this since it seems like a common need and it probably would be faster to do it without doing a native/managed transition on each file system object.  I do think that if speed is the key thing, writing a non-managed object to do this calculation and then call it once per directory from managed code.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach on 4.0-4.5 framework which I could find to calculate files size and their count on disk was:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class FileCounter
{
  private readonly int _clusterSize;
  private long _filesCount;
  private long _size;
  private long _diskSize;

  public void Count(string rootPath)
  {
    // Enumerate files (without real execution of course)
    var filesEnumerated = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath)
                              .EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    // Do in parallel
    Parallel.ForEach(filesEnumerated, GetFileSize);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Get real file size and add to total
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="fileInfo">File information</param>
  private void GetFileSize(FileInfo fileInfo)
  {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _filesCount);
    Interlocked.Add(ref _size, fileInfo.Length);
  }
}

var fcount = new FileCounter("F:\\temp");
fcount.Count();
```

This approach appeared for me as the best which I could find on .net platform. Btw if you need to calculate cluster size and real size on disk, you can do next:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private long WrapToClusterSize(long originalSize)
    {
        return ((originalSize + _clusterSize - 1) / _clusterSize) * _clusterSize;
    }

private static int GetClusterSize(string rootPath)
    {
        int sectorsPerCluster = 0, bytesPerSector = 0, numFreeClusters = 0, totalNumClusters = 0;
        if (!GetDiskFreeSpace(rootPath, ref sectorsPerCluster, ref bytesPerSector, ref numFreeClusters,
                              ref totalNumClusters))
        {
            // Satisfies rule CallGetLastErrorImmediatelyAfterPInvoke.
            // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182199(v=vs.80).aspx
            var lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error code {0}", lastError));
        }
        return sectorsPerCluster * bytesPerSector;
    }
[DllImport(Kernel32DllImport, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpace(
        string rootPath,
        ref int sectorsPerCluster,
        ref int bytesPerSector,
        ref int numFreeClusters,
        ref int totalNumClusters);
```

And of course you need to rewrite GetFileSize() in first code section:

```
private long _diskSize;
private void GetFileSize(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _filesCount);
        Interlocked.Add(ref _size, fileInfo.Length);
        Interlocked.Add(ref _diskSize, WrapToClusterSize(fileInfo.Length));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some leads in [this link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572179-quickly-calculate-folder-or-volume-size/) (though it's in Python) from a person running into similar performance issues. You can try calling down into [Win32 API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shrijeetnair/win32api12062005005528AM/win32api.aspx) to see if performance improves, but at the end you're going to run into the same issue: a task can only be done so quickly and if you have to do the task a lot of times, it will take a lot of time. Can you give more detail on what you're doing this for? It might help folks come up with a heuristic or some cheats to help you. If you're doing this calculation a lot, are you caching the results?

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite sure that this will be slow as hell,
but I'd write it like this:

```
using System.IO;

long GetDirSize(string dir) {
   return new DirectoryInfo(dir)
      .GetFiles("", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Sum(p => p.Length);
}
```