# FSO in C# .net 2010

Tags: c#, .net

I have added the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime", and I have declared :

```
using Scripting;
```

Then, I am trying to test it, I made a function :

```
private void showmessage(string path)
{
FileSystemObject fso;
label1.Text = fso.GetFileName(path); 
}
```

I am only testing if it works or not, but I got an error "use of an unassigned local variable"

Sorry if it's like silly, and please help me to solve this. God Bless You :)

Comment: thanks ^^ I'll remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize FileSystemObject before using it.

Try

```
FileSystemObject fso = new FileSystemObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
label1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)
```

In .NET you access the file system using the System.IO namespace.

Comment: except you would like to calculate the size of a folder (FAST) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665904/1498669