# How do I Get Folder Size in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, size, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a directory size (files in the directory) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118568/how-do-i-get-a-directory-size-files-in-the-directory-in-c)

In vbscript, it's incredibly simple to get the folder size in GB or MB:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fSize = CInt((oFSO.GetFolder(path).Size / 1024) / 1024)
WScript.Echo fSize
```

In C#, with all my searches, all I can come up with are long, convoluted, recursive searches for every file size in all subfolders, then add them all up at the end.

Is there no other way?

Comment: VBScript and C# run on different environments, you know. Maybe the easiest way is to run a VBScript from your app. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200422/how-to-call-a-vbscript-file-in-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: @AndreCalil: No; that is not the easiest way.

Comment: @SLaks Could you point what would be an easier way? I don't know of any builtin solution besides the sum of the files.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about this:

```
private static long GetDirectorySize(string folderPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    return di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942656/74757).

This will give you the size in bytes; you will have to "prettify" that into GBs or MBs.

**NOTE:** This only works in .NET 4+.

**EDIT:** Changed the wildcard search from `"*.*"` to `"*"` as per the comments in the thread to which I linked. This should extend its usability to other OSes (if using Mono, for example).

Comment: It's too small an edit for me to get it through but I think you meant to put `.Sum(di => di.Length);`

Comment: +1 Sincerly, I prefer this to my solution.

Comment: @Spacemancraig: No, `fi` should be correct, because we are naming each  `FileInfo` object enumerated by `di.EnumerateFiles()`.

Comment: That "prettify" can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488796/does-net-provide-an-easy-way-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc

Answer (score 4):

You can also use recursion to get all subdirectories and sum the sizes:

```
public static long GetDirectorySize(string path){
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    long size = files.Sum(x => new FileInfo(x).Length);
    foreach(string s in subdirectories)  
        size += GetDirectorySize(s);

    return size;
}
```

Comment: Correct but *"In C#, with all my searches, all I can come up with are long, convoluted, recursive searches for every file size in all subfolders, then add them all up at the end."*