# Total size of all files

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a console application and i want it to display the total size of all the files in a certain directory an example of the output would be this

```
Files in: C:\Windows
Total files: 49
Total size of all files: 7121424 bytes
```

Here is what i currently have:

```
            if (menuOption == "3")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Files in C:\\windows");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
            FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

            for (numFiles = 0; numFiles < files.Length; numFiles++)
            { 
            }
            Console.Write("Total Files: {0}",numFiles);
        }
```

As you can see i have already made it so that it gets the total amount of files in C:\Windows but im unsure how to make it add all the file sizes together. Hope you guys can give me some insight, thanks.

Comment: If you need to include the contents of subfolders this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942656/397817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `FileInfo`

```
var totalSize = files.Sum(x => x.Length);
```

Comment: logic is fine but what do we call => sign ?

Comment: @varsha it's used to create a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

By using the [FileInfo.Length Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
long totalFileSize = 0;
for (numFiles = 0; numFiles < files.Length; numFiles++)
{
    totalFileSize += files[numFiles].Length;
}
```